# Error occur as cannot resolve method/cannot resolve symbol when try to call web service in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to call web service in android. I looked various videos,tutorials,
most of them go through these steps. But when I'm coding , same code show errors. 
  .setName(),.setValue(),.setType(),.serXmlVersionTag(),.debug,.call() methods show error as "cannot resolve methods" and  HttpTransportSE and responceDump show as "cannot resolve symbol". And I'm tried to find jar on web. But it is not found too.
Can someone please help me to fix these errors?

Comment: Pl post some of your code as well as describe more about the web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`ksoap2-android`](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library in order to get it work. You can download [this jar](https://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/files/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar). Go through [How to use](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2) document also.

Comment: thanks dr.... i replaced my jar file with downloaded jar file. now it's work. previous jar file triggered without using dependencies. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before I post this question my libs folder contains "ksoap2-api-for-android.jar" .Then  when i was coding the mentioned errors are occurred.   Then I replaced my Jar file with [this jar file](https://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/files/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar). Now it is working. The reason is  my first jar file triggered without using dependencies and new one triggered with using dependencies.. :)